# adding long header according to RFC 5322 in office.js fails

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to add a custom email header which is longer than 998 characters via a outlook add-in created with office.js (and ScriptLab)

I already opened an issue on github, but maybe people here had similar issues and found a way to fix it.

Problem is that office.js checks any header for the max length of 998 characters, regardless if they are folded or not.
If I remove this check manually in the office-js lib, it seems that outlook itself complains and doesn't add the header.
Depending on the outlook version I either get the error 2006 (format error) or nothing at all.

Header value looks like this

```
my-type="urn:my:test:which:is:longer:than:998:1:0";
 my-param*0="PG1iOadpbmRpbmdJbmZvcm1hdGlvbiB4bWxuczp4c2k9Imh0dH";
 my-param*1="A6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDEvWE1MU2NoZW1hLWluc3RhbmNl";
 my-param*2="IiB4bWxdfgg4c2Q9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDEvWE";
 my-param*3="1MU2NoZW1hIiB4bWxuczpkcz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcv";
 my-param*4="MjAwMC8wOS94bWxkc2lnIyIgeG1sbnM6eG1pbWU9Imh0dHA6Ly";
 my-param*5="93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDUvMDUveG1sbWltZSIgeG1sbnM6bWI9";
 my-param*6="InVybjpuYXR934dfgfdhZzo0Nzc4OmJpbmRpbmdpbmZvcm1hdG";
 my-param*7="lvbjoxOjAiPjxtYjpNZXRhZGF0YUJpbmRpbmdDb250YWluZXI+";
 my-param*8="PG1iOk1ldGFkYXRhQmluZGluZz48bWI6TWV0YWRhdGE+PHNsYW";
 my-param*9="I6b3JpZ2luYXRvckNvbmZpZGVudGlhbGl0eUxhYmVsIHhtbG5z";
 my-param*10="OnNsYWI9InVybjpuYXRvOnN0YW5hZzo0Nzc0OmNvbmZpZGVudG";
 my-param*11="lhbGl0eW1ldGdfgfdgfdagfdaggTowIj48c2xhYjpDb25maWRl";
 my-param*12="lhbGl0eW1ldGdfgfdgfdagfdaggTowIj48c2xhYjpDb25maWRl";
 my-param*13="lhbGl0eW1ldGdfgfdgfdagfdaggTowIj48c2xhYjpDb25maWRl";
 my-param*14="lhbGl0eW1ldGdfgfdgfdagfdaggTowIj48c2xhYjpDb25maWRl";
 my-param*15="lh1sdffW1ldGFkYXRhbGFiZWw6MTowIj48c2xhYjpDb25maWRl";
```

here's how I try to add it

```
function setCustomHeaders() {
  console.log("start");
  Office.context.mailbox.item.internetHeaders.setAsync({ "my-header": data }, function(asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
      console.log("Successfully set headers");
    } else {
      console.log("Error setting headers: " + JSON.stringify(asyncResult.error));
    }
  });
}
```

it doesn't matter which client/infrastructure I use (outlook 2016, MS 365 with on prem Exchange, MS 365 with cloud).

[Here](https://gist.github.com/Arikael/b88dd54074988f0b9a64e46fdcf7d913) you find a gist which is importable in ScriptLab.

So, my question is:
Has anybody found a way to add folded headers which are longer than 998 chars (RFC 5322) succesfully to an outlook email?

**UPDATE**
Doing it with a VSTO Plugin does work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible, see https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3546#issuecomment-1664282086

> Currently the feature to add internet header with folding, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.

[I opened a feature request](https://%20https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/support-folding-headers-according-to-rfc5322-for-outlook-add-in/idi-p/3891075), on which you can vote, if you want/need that feature too.

In the meantime the only possibility is to use VSTO (and be stuck with .NET 4.8/netstandard2.0)

example for VSTO:

```
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
            if (mailItem != null)
            {
                var data = @" binding-type=""urn:nato:stanag:4778:bindinginformation:1:0"";
    binding-data-object*0=""PG1iOkJpbmRpbmdJbmZvcm1hdGlvbiB4bWxuczp4c2k9Imh0dH"";
    binding-data-object*1=""A6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDEvWE1MU2NoZW1hLWluc3RhbmNl"";
    binding-data-object*2=""IiB4bWxuczp4c2Q9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDEvWE"";
    binding-data-object*3=""1MU2NoZW1hIiB4bWxuczpkcz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcv"";
    binding-data-object*4=""MjAwMC8wOS94bWxkc2lnIyIgeG1sbnM6eG1pbWU9Imh0dHA6Ly"";
    binding-data-object*5=""93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDUvMDUveG1sbWltZSIgeG1sbnM6bWI9"";
    binding-data-object*6=""InVybjpuYXRvOnN0YW5hZzo0Nzc4OmJpbmRpbmdpbmZvcm1hdG"";
    binding-data-object*7=""lvbjoxOjAiPjxtYjpNZXRhZGF0YUJpbmRpbmdDb250YWluZXI+"";
    binding-data-object*8=""PG1iOk1ldGFkYXRhQmluZGluZz48bWI6TWV0YWRhdGE+PHNsYW"";
    binding-data-object*9=""I6b3JpZ2luYXRvckNvbmZpZGVudGlhbGl0eUxhYmVsIHhtbG5z"";
    binding-data-object*10=""OnNsYWI9InVybjpuYXRvOnN0YW5hZzo0Nzc0OmNvbmZpZGVudG"";
    binding-data-object*11=""lhbGl0eW1ldGFkYXRhbGFiZWw6MTowIj48c2xhYjpDb25maWRl"";
    binding-data-object*12=""lhbGl0eW1ldGFkYXRhbGFiZWw6MTowIj48c2xhYjpDb25maWRl"";
    binding-data-object*13=""lhbGl0eW1ldGFkYXRhbGFiZWw6MTowIj48c2xhYjpDb25maWRl"";
    binding-data-object*14=""lhbGl0eW1ldGFkYXRhbGFiZWw6MTowIj48c2xhYjpDb25maWRl"";
    binding-data-object*15=""lhbGl0eW1ldGFkYXRhbGFiZWw6MTowIj48c2xhYjpDb25maWRl"";";

                if (mailItem.EntryID == null)
                {
                    mailItem.Subject = "My subject text";
                    //mailItem.Body = "My body text";
                    mailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/my-header", data);
                }
            }
```